# Fundementals of Engineering exam with Math degree (not ABET-engineering?)

Tags: engineering, abet

Is it possible to take the [Fundamentals of Engineering](https://ncees.org/wp-content/uploads/FE-Ind-CBT-specs.pdf) to become a licensed engineer with only a math degree? I don't think a math degree is an ABET accredited "engineering program".

Comment: I don't see any requirements to sign up for the test beyond paying $225. Are you asking if it's possible to _pass_ the test?

Comment: You may be able to take the test. I'm sure they would accept your money. But becoming a licensed engineer would depend on your engineering discipline, the state you want to practice in, your experience, etc. This question may be more appropriate in [engineering.stackexchange](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this National Council of Examiners for Engineering and Surveying (NCEES) website](https://ncees.org/credentials-evaluations-policy-amended-to-expand-service/):

*The NCEES board of directors recently approved an amendment to the policy that governs the NCEES Engineering Standard to expand access to its credentials evaluations service. NCEES uses this standard to evaluate educational credentials of engineering licensure candidates **with degrees from the following**:*

- *Engineering programs outside the United States*
- ***U.S.-based programs in*** engineering, engineering technology, related science, or **mathematics that are not accredited by the Engineering Accreditation Commission of ABET, when coupled with a master’s degree or doctorate from a program that is EAC/ABET-accredited at the undergraduate or graduate level**

So, it seems that having an undergraduate degree in math is not, by itself, a showstopper for sitting for the FE exam, provided that you have a MS or PhD in engineering from an institution that is ABET-accredited, either at the undergraduate or graduate level. In this case, it sounds like you will be referred to the [NCEES Credentials Evaluations](https://ncees.org/records/ncees-credentials-evaluations/) service to have your background reviewed in order to determine if you are prepared well-enough to pursue engineering licensure.

Comment: The point here is that you need an MS or PhD in an engineering discipline from a program that is EAC/ABET accredited.  Thus completing an MS in Electrical Engineering would be OK, but even having a PhD in mathematics wouldn't be sufficient.